# odoo 8 make button invisible from compute result

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

This is my .py

```
@api.depends('product_id')
def get_sales_divisi(self):
    for line in self:
        if line.product_id.divisi_update:
            line.sales_divisi_id = line.product_id.divisi_update.id
        elif line.product_id.divisi_ids:
            line.sales_divisi_id = line.product_id.divisi_ids.ids[0]
```

this is my .xml

```
<button name="action_approve" string="Approve Checker" type="object"  attrs="{'invisible':['|',('sales_divisi_id', '=', '2'),('sales_divisi_id', 'in', ('VET'))]}" groups="ts_addons_tbk.group_tbk_checker" />
```

I'm tying to make the button invisible when the sales_divisi_id is Vet but it doesn't work. Any advice please? Thank you

Comment: what is the field type ? `sales_divisi_id`

Comment: the filed type is many2one

Comment: if it is many2one then correct `('sales_divisi_id', 'in', ('VET')` this, it will not accept this

Comment: yes but what is the correct one sir?

Comment: you can provide id..... not a character.... you can provide like `'sales_divisi_id', '=', 2` or `'sales_divisi_id', 'is', True`

Comment: Thank you. It works. I was wrong using '2' instead of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `sales_divisi_id` is a relation, `in` operator will query by `id` or `name` field.
Furthermore, in order to use fields in queries inside your views, you need to define them first.

For example:

```
<field name="sales_divisi_id" invisible="1" />
<button name="action_approve" attrs="{'invisible':[('sales_divisi_id', 'in', [1,2])]}" groups="ts_addons_tbk.group_tbk_checker" />
```

`action_approve` button will show only if `sales_divisi_id` is related to a record having `id` 1 or 2.